# Sending custom emojis by API #youtube-api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need help.

I'm trying to send custom emoticons via YouTube API to a chat, but unfortunately, it's not possible to send them in the form ":emoticon:". I suspect that the reason might be the use of HTML along the way. However, since it's possible to use Unicode to send standard icons, maybe there's another way to send a custom emoticon through the API? Perhaps you have some solution to this problem?

Using ":emoticon:" did not bring any effect, and I also couldn't find any information about custom emoticons via API. I'm actually wondering if it's even possible to send custom emoticons. For a moment I thought that it might be possible to simply send an image, but the API... that idea fall short.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the code you're using for this task?
I don't think this is possible via YouTube API - you can post a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) and hopefully, get an official response.